# how to use clob datatype field in dynamic query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I had to add few fields in the select query.

For this there is a table named `INSTRUCTION`, where in one of the field named `STEPS`, the select query is inserted with the help of a dynamic insert query.

I added the fields to be fetched, but when I ran this dynamic insert query to insert the select query into `STEPS` column/field of `INSTRUCTION` table, I had issues with the length of the `STEPS` column, its data type is `varchar2(4000)` the max length, I think now the length of the select statement that I'm trying to insert is 4850.

I tried to modify the field `STEPS` to clob and later tried to execute the same dynamic insert query for inserting into `INSTRUCTION` table, yet its again failing with `character string buffer too small`. I tried to wrap the fields im choosing in the select statement with `TO_CLOB` (field from select) for all the fields and yet its throwing the same error.

Please help me with this

Comment: Could you post your SQL statements, table structures. the associated data  and the errors that you get?

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 approach for this,

1. To change a field in table to `CLOB` data type, through googling i
   found an answer that this cannot be done with a single `ALTER` statement, we
   need to introduce a temp variable as `varchar2` and change it to long
   and then to clob. Will post the code later...
2. Below are the steps,

   - Rename the original table name to `original_table_bkp`
   - Use the same DDL used for the original table to `create` a table with same name, here we are planning to create the original table
     with data type as `CLOB`, make sure grants are also mentioned
   - `Insert` records from original_table_bkp table to original_table (with new clob data type field)
   - `drop` the original_table_bkp

   Thanks!